# Nginx variables for the subpath inside the current location or alias

Tags: nginx

Is there an Nginx variable for the subpath inside the current location, or inside the current alias?

For example, given `location /static {...}` and `GET /static/booze.png`, is there a variable containing `/booze.png`, which would be the subpath inside the current location?

Or otherwise, given `location /static { alias /srv/static-files; ...}` and the same GET, is there a variable containing `/booze.png`, the subpath inside the current alias?

I know I can use regex locations to capture it, but I'd like to avoid it if I can use a builtin variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you may try a trick like this:

```
location ~* /static/(.*)$ {
  set $subpath = $1;
}
```

The only thing you have to keep in mind - regexp locations have priority over regular ones.

Comment: A shorter and better way is to use`/static/(?<subpath>.*)$` as the location regex. Then, `$subpath` can be used directly in the location block.